# Checking a JSON response with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json

This is the ajax code that asks if a user exists in the database. The response is ok:

```
{"exists":true}
```

but the code fails on POINT 1

```
$.post('http://lajmetari.info/icb/modules/mod_facebook/tmpl/search.php',{user_id: '655879565'}, function(data){
                if(data.exists){   // POINT 1
                console.log('PO');
                    $('#container_like').show();
                        $('#container_notlike').hide(); 
                        $("#erresira").remove();
                        $("#popup").remove();
                }else{
                console.log('JO');
                    var loadUrl = "http://lajmetari.info/icb/modules/mod_facebook/tmpl/ajax.php";
                $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl+"?user_id=" + user_id);
                $('#container_like').hide();
                        $('#container_notlike').show();
                }
            }, 'JSON');
        });
```

can anyone tell me why?

thank You!

Comment: You should `console.log(data)` and check what is returned.

Comment: Run a `console.log(data)`, what does it say?

Comment: are you doing `echo json_encode` on your php side?

Comment: <?php
header('content-type: text/json');
if(!isset($_POST['user_id']))
    exit;
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***','***','***',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM icb_fcb_users WHERE user_id= :user_id');
$query->bindParam(':user_id', $_POST['user_id']);
$query->execute();
echo json_encode(array('exists' => $query->rowCount() > 0));
?>

Comment: thank You All,  after searching found that the correct condition should be:
if(JSON.parse(data).exists)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of returning JSON object with only a true/false variable you could return 404 http status code from the server when the user doesn't exists and 200 status code when it has some data.

```
$.post('http://lajmetari.info/icb/modules/mod_facebook/tmpl/search.php',{ user_id: '655879565' })
.done(function(data){
    console.log('PO');
        $('#container_like').show();
        $('#container_notlike').hide(); 
        $("#erresira").remove();
        $("#popup").remove();
})
.fail(function(){
    console.log('JO');
    var loadUrl = "http://lajmetari.info/icb/modules/mod_facebook/tmpl/ajax.php";
    $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl+"?user_id=" + user_id);
    $('#container_like').hide();
    $('#container_notlike').show();
})
```

And then u will have a clear way to handle true/false cases.

In php you could do something like this for 404:

```
<?php
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
header("Status: 404 Not Found");

$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'] = 404;
?> <!-- 404 contents below this line -->
```

Comment: "you could return 404 from the server when the user doesn't exists and 200 when it has some data." -- +1!

Comment: thank You All, after searching found that the correct condition should be: if(JSON.parse(data).exists)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(data){
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    if(obj.exists){

    }else{

    }
}
```

Comment: when you pass `dataType: 'json'` to `$.post` it will assume that the data returned is of type JSON so there is no need for `$.parseJSON` call.

Comment: Check your console for the response, even better hit the ajax page directly with the required parameters and see if the response is generated correctly or not.

Comment: in both cases the result is this: {"exists":true}

Comment: thank You All, after searching found that the correct condition should be: if(JSON.parse(data).exists)